# The Attenuation of Light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, astronomy, absorption

I have this question:

> **Show that the attenuation of light as it travels through the interstellar medium follows an exponential law**

My initial thoughts were to demonstrate the absorption of radiation using the radiative transfer equation. However, this is a short 4 mark question from a past exam paper, **AND** later in the paper you are asked to solve for the formal solution of the radiative transfer equation, so I'm guessing that I am over-looking something simple?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Exponential attenuation is the inescapable mathematical consequence of a fixed fraction of the photons being absorbed per unit distance. Another way of putting this is that the probability of a photon being absorbed per unit distance is a constant, $k$, say. This seems reasonable if the medium is (on average over distances greater than about $\frac{1}{k}$) the same over the photons' path.

Then $\frac{dN}{N}=-k\ dx\ \ $  leading to $\ \ N=N_0\ \text{exp}\ (-kx)$.